# Upserting edges dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, orientdb, upsert

My question is similar to some others, but I haven't found a solution. Closest would be 
[Can we UPSERT an EDGE in orientdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060343/can-we-upsert-an-edge-in-orientdb)

I'd like to use REST scripts against dynamic C# objects to do this:

```
LET rec = upsert non-edge record properties
foreach edge on object, upsert edge using $rec
```

The question I linked has an upsert edge query which creates an orphaned edge, even if both out and in values are inserted correctly.

Since I know the parent and the $rec var works, my backup plan is to query for the edge, then do (the /n is needed for conditionals)

```
IF ($edge_exists.size() == 0) { \n LET newEdge = CREATE EDGE...
```

But does anyone know a smoother way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can't to do an upsert in a let

Comment: It definitely works for vertices, hopefully it will come to edges soon. Thanks!